# How to pass dynamic HTML tag to a bootstrap modal?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

Consider a component common-dialog

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">  {{heading}}  </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"  ">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    BODY COMES HERE
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
     FOOTER COMES HERE
  </div>


const modalRef = this.modalService.open(CommonDialogComponent,  { size: 'lg' });


modalRef.componentInstance.heading = 'Choose an email template';
modalRef.componentInstance.body= '<h1>BODY</h1>';
```

last line will show like  **`<h1>BODY</h1>`**  in the modal ui.
how can i pass it as html tag so it render correctly in modal window.
**modalRef.componentInstance can pass only string how to pass html content.**
**I am trying to create a generic commondialog component with dynamic header ,body & footer.**

Comment: Have you tried sanitize ? https://angular.io/api/core/Sanitizer or https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer bypassSecurityTrustHtml

Comment: You are using ng-bootstrap, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is way to add html in common modal component :

```js
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">  {{heading}}  </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"  ">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body" [innerHtml]="body">
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer" [innerHtml]="footer">
     FOOTER COMES HERE
  </div>


const modalRef = this.modalService.open(CommonDialogComponent,  { size: 'lg' });


modalRef.componentInstance.heading = 'Choose an email template';
modalRef.componentInstance.body= '<h1>BODY</h1>';
modalRef.componentInstance.footer= '<h1>FOOTER</h1>';
```